# Get image profile of gmail or Google+ in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-plus

I want to get the profile image of google + gmail owner or terminal where the app is running, to work with the markers in googlemaps.

I've seen the class Person (deprecated) and GoogleApiClient latter is not operating, always gives me nullpointerexeption ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're building your GoogleApiClient properly. You need the scopes for Google Plus login and profile information. You'll also need to add the Plus api. Note that the following example assumes the class this code is in also implements the proper connection listeners.

```
// somewhere in onCreate
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                                       .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                       .addOnConnectionFAiledListener(this)
                                       .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                                       .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                                       .addApi(Plus.API)
                                       .build();

 // other code....
 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
     // Get the profile image here
 }
```